# Crear lista con parámetros de un array en Python

Tags: python, array, lista

en un código debo rellenar una lista y1 con parámetros de tal manera que los primeros X valores (no se puede determinar el tamaño ya que varía de) serán 1s, luego se añade un parámetro entre 0 y 255, y luego otra serie de valores que serán un mismo número repetido otras Y veces.

Este código se define así:

```
y1 = [np.ones([1, a[1][0]-1]), a[0][0], im_tam[0]*np.ones([1, im_tam[1]-a[1][0]])]
```

Sin embargo, el resultado de y1 es una lista que contiene [Numpy array, 234, Numpy Array] (por poner un ejemplo) cuando yo lo que quiero es que me devuelva una lista de tal manera que sea algo estilo [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 234 545 545 545 545 545], de manera que y1 sea de tamaño 1xN (siendo N el valor que depende tanto de im_tam como de a)

Básicamente quiero poder añadir esos valores de ambos array a la lista sin que sean array, sino los valores que contienen dichos array, así y1[0] sería 1 (en vez de un np.array([1,...,1])).

Muchas gracias por vuestra respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explicación

Pasa que en realidad lo que estás creando **no** es un `numpy.ndarray`, si no una lista de un `numpy.ndarray`, un (probablemente) numero y otro `numpy.ndarray`.

Otro error que hay en la logica de tu código es que el primer argumento de `np.ones` es la cantidad de dimensiones del array. Esto significa que algo como `np.ones([3,2])` crea un array de 3x2. Para que sea de una sola dimensión el iterable debe de tener un solo item.

#### Solución

No se mucho de numpy, pero parece que existe una función llamada concatenate para este proposito. Podemos usar esta función para concatenar 3 arrays, el del medio siendo una tupla de un solo numero.
A continuación, dejo el código que usé para probar:

```
import numpy as np
import random

cantidad_unos = 10
cantidad_unos2 = 20
scalar = 3

array = np.concatenate((np.ones((cantidad_unos,)),
                        (random.randrange(256),),
                        np.ones((cantidad_unos2,))*scalar
                        ))
print(array)
```

Esto produce:

```
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. 98.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.
  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]
```

Yo lo hice con constantes, pero si necesitas puedes reemplazar el valor de cada variable por lo que te paresca más adecuado (incluyendo calculos matematicos)

Comment: he probado tu código y me sale el siguiente error: 

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)

Comment: @zyder que raro... a mi me funciona bien. Hiciste algún cambio a mi código? Que versión de Python usas? Quizá sea algo sobre la versión... Revisaste que todas las variables tuvieran numeros y no otro tipo de dato?

Comment: Vale por lo visto mis array, al darles tamaño me quedan así: por ejemplo, y1a = np.ones(1,5) saldría como ([[1.,1.,1.,1.,1.]]), por tanto tengo que usar y1a[0]. He podido concatenarlo con el vector y1c, pero por alguna razón no me deja con el y1b, que es tipo int32

Comment: vale solucionado, tengo que concatenar dicho escalar como un array también @dante, por tanto y1b = np.array([a[0][0]]), y al hacer el concatenate ya me deja hacer el vector como a ti te sale ^^

Comment: Me alegro de que hayases la solución c: